# SCD - SSIS (Does it consider space as a change?)

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, ssis-2012

I am using an SCD component in my SSIS platform. I have set all my columns as changing attributes(Type 1) while setting it up.

The data from the source table to the destination table seems to look the same. But still, I see the records being updated considering it as a changed record. I observe there are spaces in the data (both trailing and leading spaces). Will SCD consider this as a change and update the table?

If yes, How can this be rectified? How can we solve this issue?

I tried implementing ltrim and rtrim to my source query but seems not to be working.
Any suggestion would be of great help.

using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: trim the data before inserting, then you will not have the problem ever

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The data types for those columns are varchar and nchar. Somewhere I feel the data types are major issue.

Comment: The SSIS SCD component can only be described as an abomination. There are so many things wrong with it. Also the tech is so out of date that the page that describes everything wrong with it has rotted away. I'm not sure what your issue is. If the data changes (including containing spaces in a different spot) then the table should be updated.

Comment: we have some thread that have ssis add  leading and trailing spaces, and it can't circumvent as far as i understand it, but the comparison can be trimmed before comparing so that it really doesn't matter

Comment: @nnk thats my concern.. Even after I use trims it doesnt work. Somewhere it shows as it works on SQL(SSMS) but while running the query through Visual Studio, it doesnt.

Comment: Can you tell if it's the source or the target that has additional spaces? Can you query the source/target directly and see if they have spaces or if they are just being added by SSIS? You probably need to narrow down where the actual issue is occurring

Comment: @AdityRadia can you share the trim code also all of code code of course